# Error while building on xcode react native

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I have worked with react native and build the project. It is showing success for Physical device(my own mobile) and also on my mac without any issues but when I am trying to build on other simulator like iphone 12, ipad etc... it is throwing below errors.

`error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBridge`

`error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider`

`error build: Undefined symbol: _RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView`

`error build: Undefined symbol: _RCTAppSetupPrepareApp`

If anyone knows the solution or if you need further clarity please let me know

PS: I have used `arch -x86_64 npm run ios` and it worked fine but it is opening only one single simulator
(iphone 12) all and if I change it does not work

Comment: Have you tried building on the command line? `npx react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 12'`

Comment: Yes I did and got the same error